# How to write "streak" query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression, gaps-and-islands, date-arithmetic

I have a table named MyDates with columns Id (INT) and MyDate (DATE).
MyDates can contain several rows with the same date.

I want to count the number of consecutive workdays, starting from today and going backwards in time, where a workday is defined as any weekday from Monday to Friday.

I have tried to write a query using cte (common table expression), but I am stuck

Lets say that today is 27. April 2023
The MyDates table contains the following seven rows:

```
1, 2023-04-17
2, 2023-04-21
3, 2023-04-24
4, 2023-04-24
5, 2023-04-25
6, 2023-04-26
7, 2023-04-27
```

I want the query to return Streak = 5

That is because the streak should count the four dates from Thursday 2023-14-27 to Monday 2023-04-24, plus Friday 2023-04-21.

The query should ignore Saturday 2023-04-22 and Sunday 2023-04-23, and it should ignore the fact that there are to rows for Monday 2023-04-24

```sql
SELECT MIN(date) AS start_date, MAX(date) AS end_date, COUNT(*) AS streak_length
FROM (
  SELECT date, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS rn, 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY value >= threshold, is_weekend ORDER BY date) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT date, value,
           CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK(date) IN (1, 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS is_weekend
    FROM table_name
  ) sub
) sub
WHERE value >= threshold
GROUP BY value, grp - rn
ORDER BY start_date;
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (DAYOFWEEK is a product specific function.)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: _following six rows_?

Comment: Sorry - seven rows

Comment: Typo?   2023-14-27

Comment: Should it ignore saturday and sunday because they aren't present in the data or should it ignore them because they are weekend days. I'm asking to understand if this "Streak" is just defined by workdays or if it's more of a gap-and-islands problem.

Comment: Sounds like a **gaps and islands** problem to me.

Comment: Saturdays and Sundays should be ignored, because only workdays should count.
Yes "Gaps and islands " is a relevant description

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step approach at this gaps-and-islands problem.

We would start by deduplicating the dates, and associating the "previous" date with `lag()`; just in case, we can also exclude dates that fall on week-ends, if any:

```
select date, lag(date) over(order by date) lag_date
from mytable
where datepart(weekday, date) not in (1, 7)
group by date
```

From there on, we can use a conditional sum to define groups of "adjacent" records (aka *islands*) ; the trick is to adjust the date arithmetic when we meet a week-end:

```
select t.*, 
    sum(
        case when date = dateadd(
            day, 
            case when datepart(weekday, lag_date) = 6 then 3 else 1 end,
            lag_date
        ) then 0 else 1 end) over(order by date desc) grp
from (
    select date, lag(date) over(order by date) lag_date
    from mytable
    group by date
) t
```

The final step is to retain the first group only (that corresponds to the most recent streak):

```
select min(lag_date) streak_start, max(date) streak_end,
    count(*) + 1 streak_length
from (
    select t.*, 
        sum(
            case when date = dateadd(
                day, 
                case when datepart(weekday, lag_date) = 6 then 3 else 1 end,
                lag_date
            ) then 0 else 1 end) over(order by date desc) grp
    from (
        select date, lag(date) over(order by date) lag_date
        from mytable
        where datepart(weekday, date) not in (1, 7)
        group by date
    ) t
) t
where grp = 0
```

| streak_start | streak_end | streak_length |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-04-21 | 2023-04-27 | 5 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KkxIgra-)

---

Important note: `dayofweek`, that is used in your original query, is not a thing in SQL Server. We use `datepart(weekday, ...)` instead. However please note that the result of this function depend on how you set the `datefirst` parameter. The answer here assumes `set datefirst 7` (meaning that dates weeks start on Sunday, as implied by your original code).

Comment: Brilliant! 
I have asked ChatGPT to solve this problem, but it failed :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

```sql
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT  dt
    ,   (DATEPART(DW, dt) + @@DATEFIRST + 5) % 7 + 1 AS weekDay
    FROM    (
        VALUES  (N'2023-04-17')
        ,   (N'2023-04-21')
        ,   (N'2023-04-24')
        ,   (N'2023-04-24')
        ,   (N'2023-04-25')
        ,   (N'2023-04-26')
        ,   (N'2023-04-27')
    ) t (dt)
    )

SELECT  TOP 1 COUNT(DISTINCT dt), groupstreak
FROM    (
    SELECT  *
    ,   SUM(changeStreak) OVER(ORDER BY dt) AS groupStreak
    FROM    (
        SELECT  *
        ,   CASE WHEN datediff(day, LAG(dt) OVER(ORDER BY dt), dt) > CASE WHEN weekday = 1 THEN 3 ELSE 1 END THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS changeStreak
        FROM    cte 
        WHERE   weekday BETWEEN 1 AND 5
        )x
    ) x
GROUP BY groupstreak
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

I first calculate work days only, then check difference to previous day, if it's over 1 (or 3 on monday), then it's considered a streak break, finally i do a group by aggregated streak break, which gives us unique groups. Then you just take the highest count for the groups

Comment: Not sure i follow you but the code runs fine here at least :D